# How to monitor video and https traffic using bro network security monitor

Tags: network-traffic, bro

I have configured bro on my system successfully. OS is centos 7. I have to monotor multimedia traffic e.g. youtube and some social site like facebook. I started bro for some miniutes while using facebook and youtube but their is no information about youtube in http log file nithir facebook. As for I think that this is a protocol problem as facebook use https rather than http but I do not know why youtube.

I have followed following steps after setting correct interface.

```
[BroControl] > install
```

Then

```
[BroControl] > start
```

But I have not found any youtube or facebook info in http.log. How to get traffic info of such websites?

Comment: Please tell us what you have done to troubleshoot this so far. How is your node.cfg configured? Have you verified that you can see the relevant data using TCPDump. If `https` is in use, are you doing anything to decrypt the data? If not, I'm not sure why you would *expect* to read the content and I'm also not sure why you'd look in the http.log. Check the ssl.log for certificate information.  I also think you'll find if you look that Youtube is also over HTTPS by default.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are expecting SSL encrypted traffic to be magically decrypted and appear in your `http.log`.  If you look again, you will find that YouTube also runs over HTTPS.

Unless you are doing something to intercept and act as a man-in-the-middle for the SSL/TLS connections, you cannot expect to be able to see the content. If you can't see it, Bro can't see it either. :)

If you want to verify that you are properly configured, you would be best served looking at the `conn.log` to verify that the connections are occurring. Once you do that, search for the `UID` values in the other logs and I strongly suspect that you will see that you are finding SSL certificate data.

Comment: Sir, I do not want to see the content, I need just meta data (content length) only. Actucally, I have to find how mutch data of facebook is transfered only.

Comment: Then use the conn.log to see how many bytes were transferred.

Comment: I have posted a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509155/how-to-capture-metadata-for-https-traffic-using-bro-ids. Please guide if you can

Answer (score 0):

Several things come to mind

1) What are the contents of `/usr/local/bro/etc/node.cfg`? Make sure it is the interface you expect traffic to cross via a span or tap.

2) Run `tcpdump -i <interface>` where interface comes from question 1.

3) Run `/usr/local/bro/bin/broctl diag` to see if there are any issues.

4) Run `/usr/local/bro/bin/broctl status` to verify everything is running.

If the interface is wrong, the solution may be that easy.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @TomSlick re-evaluate this. The provided information in the original post was not adequate to really render a necessary answer. I reworded the response to be more of an answer. However, it is a non-trivial problem and unless you understand the underlying software it is hard to describe adequately in a finite space.

Comment: @TomSlick This is perfectly valid troubleshooting advice to a really broad question. Starting from the premise that the interface is likely misconfigured, this is a relevant answer. That may not be the issue, however.