# why bro ids does not show youtube traffic by default

Tags: networking, youtube, bro

I have configured bro IDS on my centos system. I have all default configuration. I have started bro by simply `broctl start` and then I played some vides in youtube and open some other sites. I am amazed that in logs (like http.log) contains other sites statistics but there is not information about youtube. 
I have used `tcpdump` to capture youtube traffic like following command.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 src host www.youtube.com -w youtube-traffic.pcap
```

In order to analyze, then I run following command

```
broctl -r youtube-traffic.pcap local
```

A lot of logs generated but there is no http.log. I think that there should be atleast some information in http.log.
Where is the problem? why bro does not capture youtube traffic ? how to monitor youtube traffic ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to monitor video and https traffic using bro network security monitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116135/how-to-monitor-video-and-https-traffic-using-bro-network-security-monitor)

Comment: Asking the same question with different words is still a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube only does encrypted traffic (HTTPS).  The only evidence of youtube you will find will be in ssl.log and x509.log.